# React MobileStepper always 50%

Tags: reactjs

Is there an option to tell the react Material-UI MobileStepper to be on 100% width? I believe it is on 50% fixed because they expect Buttons on left and right side.

I adjusted the example of the Material-UI Mobile Stepper to reproduce the issue: https://codesandbox.io/s/048348ojjl

Any idea how to extend the width to 100%?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to style the `MobileStepper` via a [Higher Order Component](https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#shorthand). If you wish to adjust any of the other `child` elements, then see this [doc](https://material-ui.com/api/mobile-stepper/#css).

Side note: Setting the `width` to `100%` clashes with the buttons. So the current `width` is set to `75%`.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/q3xxwkwy69

Comment: This is the correct react like solution, but anyways I consider this as a bug of the Material-ui component. :) Thank you very much.